# Can't filter a column to see all cells containing `@` in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets

I'm trying to filter a column to show cells that contain `@` (as in an email address) but when I put `@` in the filter box it comes up with a blank.

Any ideas?

[An example spreadsheet here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1z9lu27zIYpqXVRiKVqQykrSzNwI4z5Qvtus6LCKiGWo/edit#gid=0). Here is also a screenshot:

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The characters you enter in the filter box are matched to the **beginning** of any word in the cell content. So, @ will match "a @ b" or "a @b", but not "a@b".

To filter based on a pattern that is not a beginning of a word, you can use a workaround with `REGEXMATCH`, e.g., entering in another column:

```
=IF(REGEXMATCH(A2,"@"),"email","not email")
```

and then filtering based on that column.

**However**, the presence of @ does not guarantee you have a valid email there. I recommend using the `ISEMAIL` function for accurate filtering: create a column with

```
=ISEMAIL(A2)
```

and then filter on TRUE value in that column.

Answer (score 0):

I've the same trouble, but I need to filter by "/".
It's incredible it doesn't exist an "escape" way ...

By now I solved (in a Pivot) creating a filter by condition.